# Maven project doesn't recognize any classes from included sibling dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have the following project structure:

```
myproj
  +---myproj-parent
  +---myproj-data (war)
  +---myproj-util
  +---myproj-report (dependency on myproj-data)
```

I am able to "mvn clean install" the "myproj-data" and "myproj-util" projects and verify they are in my local repo by viewing the directories.  In eclipse for the myproj-report pom.xml, I can also "right-click --> Maven --> Add Dependency", select both of them (e.g. "myproj-data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" and "myproj-util-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"), and everything up to this point seems is good.

The problem is that none of the classes in the myproj-data are available in myproj-report.  That is, they all show the " cannot be resolved to a type" in eclipse, and produce the "package myproj.data.model.entity does not exist" and "cannot find symbol" errors when building from the command line. As best I can tell, the "myproj-data" and "myproj-util" projects are very similarly structured, with the only major differences being packaging type and several additional dependencies in myproj-data (for jpa and REST).

I have tried:

1. clearing and rebuilding my local repo
2. rebuilding and reinstalling the myprojc-data project (mvn clean install -U)
3. removing and readding the myproj-data dependency
4. deleting and recreating workspace
5. removing and reimporting all projects (deleting .settings, target, .classpath, .project)
6. triple checking versions, names, and everything else I can think of, etc..

...but I cannot figure out why the myproj-util dependencies are being recognized when the myproj-data are not.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Because it is a WAR. So you need to attach the classes and depend on that instead.

Comment: i don't follow?  how exactly do I attach the classes (vs. the war as a whole)?

Comment: You can refer to the question I linked you to (there's the link on top of your question). Basically, you configure `maven-war-plugin` with `attachClasses` and then you depend on it with the classifier `classes`.

Comment: Sheesh.  I've been so wrapped around the axle on this one, I completely missed the link at the top.  that was it, thank you very much!